# Query by Form: How to incorporate date ranges taken from a form

Tags: forms, vba

The following code doesn't seem to work (added in the criteria of the query in MS Access). When I try the condition only with the dtDateFrom it works fine, but when I apply the second condition its never works.

> =[Forms]![frm_generate_reports]![dtDateFrom] And <=[Forms]![frm_generate_reports]![dtDateTo]

Comment: It is unable to retrieve the dtDateTo data from the form "frm_generate_repots", even though it is populated.

Answer (score 0):

The code below compares two dates

```
'Check if dates are valid

If Me.dtDateTo <= Me.dtDateFrom Then

    'Pop up message asking the user to change the dates as they are not valid
    MsgBox ("Sorry, the 'To' Date cannot occur before the 'From' date" & vbCrLf & "Please choose a different date range")

      Else
    'Do Something else
End If
```

Your code doesn't work because of the AND - its meant to test two conditions for true, usually.

Example

a = 5

If a < 10 AND a > 4
          Do Something

Both these conditions need to be true for it to work

Comment: The code you have provided is straight forward and can be used in VBA but my query was regarding applying the same in the Criteria Part of a query.

Comment: you mean in the SQL view of a query? or building a query in VBA?

Comment: building of the query, where you select the table names and then totals etc